# Angular 2: [(ngModel)] generates error on my PC yet same code works on Plunkr

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript

I've been following a tutorial and hit a brick wall yesterday when it came to the 2 way data binding with the ngModel.  After researching I discovered Plunkr and decided to make one to see if maybe it's just my computer.  Sure enough everything works as it's suppose to, so now I'm stuck trying to figure out what went wrong.  Everything worked fine until it came to the part with using [(ngModel)] in the code, I started getting thise error

> zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

the instance of the code triggering it is in the template of the app.component which is

```
<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
```

here's the plunkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4BFVVhrfHWopUqwfO9v?p=preview

I'm using Windows Vista 32bit, NodeJS 5.0.7 and npm 3.6.0.

My package.json file looks like this

```
    {
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
     "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "licenses": [
     {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

does anybody see something with the versions of the different packages that might be causing this issue?

Comment: You most probably forgot to add FormsModule in the imports attribute of your root NgModule.

Comment: actually it's in there, I copied and pasted the code into plunkr and it runs perfectly fine, it just throws errors when run from my computer.

Comment: Open the dev tools, and disable the cache (in the Network tab). Then refresh the page. Check what the content of the downloaded files (in the Sources tab)

Comment: ok just did that and the sources tab is empty